# Searlize with Column Decorator

Tags: c#, json

I have a class where the properties have decorators when I serialize a json string I am expecting to bind the data with the Column decorator case. but its not taking in such a way.

```
public class SaveDtails
{
    [Column("DetailId")]
    public Guid? detailUid { get; set; }
}
```

When serialize with the below code

```
string jSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtpod);
```

I am expecting the Json as

```
{"DetailId" :"value"}
```

instead of

```
{"detailUid" :"value"}
```

Comment: That is called an `Attribute` and it is part of the class not the data.  If you deserialize intoi a class which also has that `Attribute` all should be well.  Serializating doesnt act on meta data

Comment: You mean `[JsonProperty("DetailId")]`. Unless the class is marked as `[Serializable]`. In this case, you should implement `ISerializable` and return the property name in the `GetObjectData` method.